# Angular x Firebase, firebase wont output data in DOM, 'GET request'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-realtime-database

I have a realtime database in Firebase, and the POST request works, When I want to get the info from the database and GET it into the HTML file, it wont work and in the console its showing me this error: "*Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays*."

**http.service.ts**

```
//GET users
  getUsers() {
    return this.http
      .get(
        'https://n22-f7ae3-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json'
      )
      .pipe(
        map((res) => {
          return res;
        })
      );
  }
```

**home.component.ts**

```
newUser: any;

//I have called it in 'ngOnInit' too.
getAllUsers() {
    this.http.getUsers().subscribe((res) => {
      this.newUser = res;
    });
  }
```

**home.component.html**

```
<tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let list of newUser">
        <th scope="row">{{ list.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ list.user }}</td>
        <td>{{ list.mail }}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: `users.json` should be an array.

Comment: @N.F. has the gist of it. What data do you have at `https://n22-f7ae3-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/users.json` in the database? Most likely it's an object with key-value pairs, in which case you may want to start from `Object.keys(newUsers)`.